# Find the nearest point on a Cartesian plane?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

There are random points on a Cartesian Plane. Like PlottedPointName(a,b,c) with X-coordinates(2,4,2) and Y-coordinates(6,3,4) and if we find the nearest point to findNearestPointTo(a,b) which is NearestPointName(c) which is nearest to Point(a) and NearestPointName(c) which is nearest to Point(b).

I have written the code for it with time complexity O(n^3). By computing the distance from findNearestPointTo(a,b) to all other points and find the minimum.

```
string[] PlottedPointName={"a","b","c"};
int[] x_cord = {2,4,2};
int[] y_cord = {6,3,4};

int min = 0;
int distance =0;
string[] findNearestPointTo = {"a", "b"};
string[] nearestPoints= new string[findNearestPointTo.length];

for(int i=0;i<findNearestPointTo.length;i++)
 {
   min=0;
   for(int j=0;j<PlottedPointName.lenght;j++)
     {
        if(findNearestPointTo[i]==points[j])
          {
            for(int k=0;k<PlottedPointName.length;k++)
             {
               if(k!=j){
               distance = abs(x_cord[i] - x_cord[k]) + abs(y_cord[i] - y_cord[k]);
               if(min==0)
                 {
                   min=distance;
                   nearestPoints[i]= PlottedPointName[k];
                 }
                else if(min>0)
                 {
                   if(min>distance)
                     {
                       min= distance;
                       nearestPoints[i]= PlottedPointName[k];
                     }
                 }
                }
             } 
          }
     }
 }
```

Is there is possibility to make this code more efficient with lesser time complexity.

Comment: `if(findNearestPointTo[i]==points[j])` why are you checking this ?

Comment: @Cid he needs to find the index, because `findNearestPointTo` is defined as string.

Comment: Ah of course, for the coordinates

Comment: Could be using a struct/class to store them as reference, that will save 1 loop and goes to O(n²)

Comment: I don't think you would have any better solution than this. You need one cycle to go through each target `findNearestPointTo`, another to find the index for each `findNearestPointTo`, then the third to calcualte the distance - that's what you did.
Actually it is O(n^2), because the outer loop is not N, but the number of targets.

Comment: @Cid because first I need to find the index of point defined in `findNearestPointTo` array in `points` array. So, that I can get the X-cord and Y_cord of this point and then find the distance to all points and find minimum.

Comment: If you have 100 points, but 2 targets, it is going to take 2*100*100 steps - that's why it is O(n^2).

Comment: But in worst case. If there is 100 points and 100 targets, then I think it is O(n^3).

Comment: Well, we should define it as O(N^2)*O(M), where N is your points, and M is your targets. - which is O(N^3) is N and M are the same.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of "if we find the nearest point to point(a,b) which is c and c", nor doI understand what point(a,b) stands for in a 3D space.

Comment: Why test if `min>0`? How could it fail to be? You have already detected it is not zero, and it is assigned to from `abs(...)` so it must be greater than 0.

Comment: @YvesDaoust point(a,b) is the target points which I need to find the nearest points to them from points which is randomly plotted on 2d Cartesian Plane. like point(a,b,c).

Comment: Rather than zero your variable `min`, set it to the first item in the `for` loop and iterate from the second item onwards. Then you won't have to keep testing whether it is zero in every iteration.

Comment: @suleman: even less clear. What do you mean by "point(a,b)" ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Point(a,b) are point names like name "a" and "b" which is plotted on 2d Cartesian Plane

Comment: @my question is about the notation point(a,b), and why you mix point(a,b) and point(a,b,c). Be aware that "if we find the nearest point to point(a,b) which is c and c" is meaningless.

Comment: I suspect that you can do much better than O(N³) but the question is too unclear. Nearest point to a given one ? Closest pair ? All nearest neighbors ?

Comment: I don't understand your question too. If you have problems with exact formulation, give clear example, please.

Comment: I updated the question. kindly review it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's just one optimisation I can recommend:

After you found the point in `if(findNearestPointTo[i]==points[j])`, you can `break` from that loop, as the last statement of the  `if` block.

You can do that because we can suppose that no two points will have the same name, so this condition is guaranteed to be `false`.

It does not decrease the factor, it's going to be O(n^2), but in practice if will roughly halve the time (the constant factor is halved).

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it in O(n^2) without using the first loop ,as your query array size and the array you want to return will have sam size so if your condition that the cordinates are equal and query name is same as of the point in iteration ,and all other condition are true just simply add the name of city to the nearestCity array at index which will be same for the query which you are checking for

Comment: A simple example would be great with explanation.